# How to handle failure in API gateway

Tags: microservices

Say I design a microservice architecture for a system of payment and a user one click the pay button in its UI screen send request for an API gateway and the gateway start chain of api calls to the few microservices. how to handle to case when one of the micorservices is down or not responding in the middle of the chain call?
I want the user to think that his payment has been successful and no to return him "try again later" can I save the state of the chain somewhere?

Comment: If you want your micro-service Up all the time, you need to make a replica of your micro-service and place load-balancer against it. If one instance is down, the load balancer will automatically route the request to the instance which is alive.

Answer (score 0):

For such cases using **asynchronous** communication is more preferable rather than synchronous communication.

In this case;

When client sends a request to the system, API gateway takes the request and delegates to corresponding microservice. After that this microservice sends an event to other related microservice. Generally a message broker is used for this, messages are stored in broker and even the consumer (subcsriber) microservice is down, the message would not be lost.

You can also send events directly from api gateway to message broker. (see: https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html)

For achiving atomicity and consistency (eventual consistency of course) SAGA pattern can be applied. You can [check](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html) this for more information.

But if your requirement is calling a microservice for getting some data immediately and if this required microservice is down, then this solution would not work. You should avoid this kind of coupling between microservices by design. In my opinion, this is one of the most challenging part in microservices architecture. Domain Driven Design techniques can be used to determine bounded contexts.